# orderBy + cache is invoking work on mesos cluster

Tags: apache-spark

Spark Version: 1.3.1

Cluster: Mesos 0.22.0

Scala Version: 2.10.4

I am seeing work done on my cluster when invoking cache on an rdd. I would have expected the last line of the code below to not invoke any cluster work. Is there some condition where cache will do cluster work?

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
// work is done to load the json into the dataframe
val people = sc.parallelize(
  """{"name":"Yin","address":{"city":"Columbus","state":"Ohio"}}""" :: Nil
)
val peoplDF = sqlContext.jsonRDD(people).toDF()
// No work is done for the orderBy, as expected
val orderBy = peoplDF.orderBy("name")
// Jobs are run when invoking cache, expectation was nothing would run on the cluster
val orderByCache = orderBy.cache
```

Comment: Yesterday I encountered almost the same behavior (though in my case the query didn't had any ordering and Spark was in local mode). Personally I think this is a bug in Spark QueryExecution (or somewhere around it).

Comment: df.toJavaRDD also seems to trigger the job execution in case there is a 'orderBy' somewhethe in input dataframe.